# Strict Secure Cookie policy does not allow setting a secure cookie for http://googleads.g.doubleclick.net/

Tags: android, android-studio, admob, ads, native-ads

Hey guys I am trying to implement a native ad in my android app but it showing some error.

**Error**

```
2021-06-22 18:35:34.049 1915-2099/com.rishav.firebasedemo E/chromium: [ERROR:cookie_manager.cc(137)] Strict Secure Cookie policy does not allow setting a secure cookie for http://googleads.g.doubleclick.net/ for apps targeting >= R. Please either use the 'https:' scheme for this URL or omit the 'Secure' directive in the cookie value.
```

I looked for other StackOverflow solutions they saying that it is due to the wrong way of implementation of AdMob ads, like overlapping or any other thing but I placed my native ad very safely and far from the main app items.

Here's the screenshot of the implementation.

**Screenshot**
[image]

Comment: show your code snippet